# Block Main Thread While Other Threads in Foreach Loop are Running

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am creating a new thread to execute some code during each iteration of a foreach loop.  After these threads complete, I want the main thread to continue execution, however I am not sure how to do this.  I cannot call `Thread.Join()` for each iteration, because this will block the main thread from continuing the foreach loop until the created thread has completed.  Here is the code block, where `testEnvironments` is a List of type string:

```
        foreach (string s in testEnvironments)
        {
            myThread = new Thread(() => program.KickoffPricing(s));
            myThread.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        email.ComposeEmail();
```

Comment: I hope that isn't a UI thread.

Comment: It's not a UI thread.  This is a console application.

Comment: Are you trying to run all the threads at once?  Or do you want to run a thread, wait, and then run another thread?  If the latter, does this really need to be on a separate thread?

Comment: I am wanting to run each thread concurrently, then call the ComposeEmail method when all of them are finished.

Comment: Then depending on what .Net/C# versions you're using, the method SLaks is suggesting would be good.  If those constructs aren't available, then a collection of `ManualResetEvent` objects would an alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to store all of the `Thread`s in a `List<Thread>` and make a separate `foreach` loop that `Join()`s them after you start all of them.

Note that you can make your code simpler and more efficient by using `Task` instead of `Thread`, or, better yet, `Parallel.ForEach()`.

Comment: The Parallel.ForEach loop worked very well.  If I create a list for the threads created in that loop, how will you be able to call Thread.Join on then without blocking the calling thread (the main application thread)?  It seems like when you called Thread.Join it would block the foreach loop from running.

Comment: That's exactly what it would do, one thread at a time.  As each thread finishes, the Join returns control to the foreach, which then repeats the process with the next one until all threads have completed.